# How to handle errors during tweet extraction using python?

Tags: python, loops, exception, tweepy

I'm trying extract a dataset using tweepy. I have a set of tweet Ids that I use to extract full text tweets. I have looped the IDs and tweepy functions to get the tweet texts, but my program keeps crashing because a few of the tweet IDs on my list are from suspended accounts.

This is the related code snippet I'm using:

```py
    # Creating DataFrame using pandas
    db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username', 'description', 'location', 'following',
                               'followers', 'totaltweets', 'retweetcount', 'text', 'hashtags'])

    #reading tweet IDs from file 
    df = pd.read_excel('dataid.xlsx') 
    mylist = df['tweet_id'].tolist()

    #tweet counter
    n=1

    #looping for extract tweets
    for i in mylist:
        tweets=api.get_status(i, tweet_mode="extended")
        username = tweets.user.screen_name
        description = tweets.user.description
        location = tweets.user.location
        following = tweets.user.friends_count
        followers = tweets.user.followers_count
        totaltweets = tweets.user.statuses_count
        retweetcount = tweets.retweet_count
        text=tweets.full_text
        hashtext = list()
        ith_tweet = [username, description, location, following,followers, totaltweets, retweetcount, text, hashtext]
        db.loc[len(db)] = ith_tweet
        n=n+1

    filename = 'scraped_tweets.csv'
```

Comment: are you looking for [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)?

Comment: Is your error coming from the line starting with tweets=api.get_status... ?  The line that causes the error needs to be handled with try/except as Matiiss recommends.

Comment: @LeeExothermix  yes I think you're right I need to put it in a try/except but I'm not sure if it just that line I need to include or the rest of the code as well.

Comment: @Matiiss yes but can you tell me which line I should be including in the try/exception?

Comment: @Liya the one that raises the exception, just put it inside and in the `except` (specify the exception, don't just have `except:`) block just place `continue`

Comment: @Matiiss thank you so much!! much appreciated